# Dart how do I remove LatLng object and just have the coordinates

Tags: dart

Hi I have recently started using Dart for flutter, I am wondering when I have a `LatLng` object but need to convert it to a string by using `.toString()` method how can I remove the `LatLng` part and just have the values I have tried using `trim` and `replaceAll` but it doesn't work

Eg:

```
location = LatLng(55.5595959, 6.48484864);
```

I just want to see  55.5595959, 6.48484864

Comment: Just to be sure. You want `location.toString()` to output "55.5595959, 6.48484864"?

Comment: Yeah that's what I am looking for

Answer (score 2):

You can't override the `.toString()` method without extending the class, what you can do is creating an extension for your class to return the wanted string:

```
void main() {
  var location = LatLng(55.5595959, 6.48484864);
  print(location.toStringCoordinates());
}

extension LatLngString on LatLng {
  String toStringCoordinates() => '$latitude, $longitude';
}
```